# Sharing QGIS Project that connects to local postGIS database

Tags: qgis, postgis, spatial-database

I am looking to share a QGIS project with a few others outside my network. The QGIS project is using layers from a postGIS database I created locally. I am wondering what the best way is to go about sharing the project and granting access to the database files. Is it possible to allow them remote access to my database, or should they just create their own databases with the same files?

Comment: Your best plan is to remove your hard drive and mail it to them

Comment: See for example [How to Allow Remote Access to PostgreSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580066/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-postgresql-database)